# Dynamic button, textbox and picturebox creation

Tags: c#, dynamic

Here I am doing a project where questions are presented in images. When the project loads, "start exam" button will be present in the screen. After pressing the button, it should create a `picturebox`, a `textbox` and a `button` for each image from specified path. Then users has to enter the answer in a `textbox` which is created dynamically. After the dynamic submit `button` is clicked for every image, the `textbox` values have to be stored in the `listbox`. I don't know how get the values from `textbox`. Can anyone help me out from this?

Here is my code:

```
PictureBox[] pics = new PictureBox[100];
TextBox[] txts = new TextBox[100];
Button[] butns = new Button[100];
FlowLayoutPanel[] flws = new FlowLayoutPanel[100];

private void button1_Click( Object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        flws[i] = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flws[i].Name = "flw" + i;
        flws[i].Location = new Point(3,brh);
        flws[i].Size = new Size(317,122);
        flws[i].BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
        flws[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        pics[i] = new PictureBox();
        pics[i].Location = new Point(953, 95 + brh);
        pics[i].Name = "pic" + i;
        pics[i].Size = new Size(300, 75);
        pics[i].ImageLocation = "C:/" + listBox1.Items[i];
        flws[i].Controls.Add(pics[i]);
        txts[i] = new TextBox();
        txts[i].Name = "txt" + i;
        txts[i].Location = new Point(953, 186 + brh);
        flws[i].Controls.Add(txts[i]);
        butns[i] = new Button();
        butns[i].Click += new EventHandler(butns_Click);
        butns[i].Text = "submit";
        butns[i].Name = "but" + i;
        butns[i].Location = new Point(1100, 186 + brh);
        flws[i].Controls.Add(butns[i]);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flws[i]);
        brh += 130;
    }
}

private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button butns = sender as Button;
    TextBox txts = sender as TextBox; 
    listBox2.Items.Add("text values " + txts.Text.ToString());
}
```

Comment: why use **100** `FlowLayoutPanel`!Isn't 1 sufficient..Why not use list instead of array..

Answer (score 0):

I would create a usercontrol to combine the controls.

Search for "custom usercontrol c#"

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button butns = sender as Button;
    string btnName = butns.Name;
    string Id = btnName.Substring(3);
    string txtName = "txt" + Id;
    listBox2.Items.Add("text values " + GetValue(txtName));
}

private string GetValue(string name)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Name = name;
    foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is FlowLayoutPanel)
        {
            foreach (Control i in ctl.Controls)
            {
                if (((TextBox)i).Name == txt.Name)
                {
                    txt = (TextBox)i;
                    return txt.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return txt.Text;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . But i'm getting NullRefferenceException for txts.Name = "txt" +Id ;

Comment: ya its correct . I've tried another method . its working. thanks dude